# markowitz portfolio optimization using quadratic programming and convex solver

Tags: python, numpy, portfolio, cvxopt

I'm using python code lifted from a quantopian blog in order to find an optimized portfolio.

I've gone through the entire exercise detailed here: https://blog.quantopian.com/markowitz-portfolio-optimization-2/

Everything works like a charm until the last equation in the optimal_portfolio function:

`wt = solvers.qp(opt.matrix(x1 * S), -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x']`

where I get a super messy error:

C:\Software\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\cvxopt\coneprog.py in `qp(P, q, G, h, A, b, solver, initvals, **kwargs)
   4466             'residual as dual infeasibility certificate': dinfres} 
   4467 
-> 4468     return coneqp(P, q, G, h, None, A,  b, initvals, options = options)`

C:\Software\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\cvxopt\coneprog.py in `coneqp(P, q, G, h, dims, A, b, initvals, kktsolver, xnewcopy, xdot, xaxpy, xscal, ynewcopy, ydot, yaxpy, yscal, **kwargs)
   2241         # lmbdasq = lambda o lambda.
   2242 
-> 2243         if iters == 0:  W = misc.compute_scaling(s, z, lmbda, dims)
   2244         misc.ssqr(lmbdasq, lmbda, dims)
   2245`

C:\Software\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\cvxopt-1.1.8-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\cvxopt\misc.py in `compute_scaling(s, z, lmbda, dims, mnl)
    283 
    284     m = dims['l']
--> 285     W['d'] = base.sqrt( base.div( s[mnl:mnl+m], z[mnl:mnl+m] ))
    286     W['di'] = W['d']**-1
    287     lmbda[mnl:mnl+m] = base.sqrt( base.mul( s[mnl:mnl+m], z[mnl:mnl+m] ) )`

ValueError: domain error

it appears that I might be trying to take the sqrt of a negative number. Any ideas on how to address this?

Comment: Are you using the demonstration code to populate parameters?

Comment: No, I'm loading the returns matrix from a csv file of my own. it works properly for the random_portfolio function.